# Is react-native in conjunction with Sentry javascript .sdk capable of handling offline logging

Tags: sentry, error-logging

I am not a developer but am assisting in the diagnosis of an app problem  - Android and Apple.

The team has begun to use Sentry, however it does not capture any exceptions once the app goes offline.

The team would like to know if there are any add-ons to Sentry to sync and or capture offline data within the app.

We are using react-native and javascript.sdk.

Real life case scenario: App goes into offline mode (captured/recognised) > some actions will go into the offline/sync/pending queue - the rest will cause the app to crash.

How to capture the offline exceptions using Sentry?

Comment: Welcome Aboard! Please read before ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask